# How to connect to a remote VM using vagrant?

Tags: networking, ssh, virtualbox, lan, vagrant

I have two Windows 7 machines in my local network.

One Windows 7 with Virtual Box (running Ubuntu) installed.

Is it possible to connect to the Ubuntu from another machine by using vagrant ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So essentially you are trying to access/manage a VirtualBox VM on a remote host with Vagrant? Nope, that's not possible currently with the existing Vagrant-VirtualBox provider :( Though there are solutions for other platforms like EC2 https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant-aws/ that accomplish roughly the same...

Comment: Yes, that's what I want. Thank you. Is it possible to connect to it through ssh ?

Comment: Where do you want to connect to via ssh?

Comment: Sorry for my English. I have 2 PCs (A and B) in local network. A has Virtual Box installed. The guest system is Ubuntu. What I want is to connect Ubuntu via ssh from B. I finally figure out how to do it now. By setting the virtual machine network type to bridged, make Ubuntu visible in the local network. I am able to ssh it from B now. Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

In your vagrant file, use a bridged network type then you can access it from another machine. This line for example:

config.vm.network :public_network